# Building a mobile app map-based for a non-profit animal welfare organization

Tags: google-maps, mobile, user-input

Can anyone give me some basic directions to keep me going?

My general requirements for this application

1. country street map (ok)
2. Six different categories of PINS for volunteers to use eg Lost, Found, Alert etc (no idea how to provide that
3. Pin category filter to show on the map
4. permanent pins and non permanent
5. it will also be linked to website

Are there any tutorials or advice you can provide to help get me going on this project?

Comment: Your question is perhaps more suited for programmers.stackexchange.com. It likely will be migrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check out appcelerator.com it's mobile development product titanium I think has everything your looking for. Maps are quite easy to do in it and the pins your talking about are called annotations in the API you are able to specify images for them, this could be how you categorise them by showing a diff color or image all together, then by using an SQLite db in ur app you can make a list of them and pull out which ever ones you need.

Comment: i m checking asap Thank you very much